# Having issue with react-router-dom version 6 when I import components with <Link />, <NavLink /> in a mono-repo

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a mono-repo where we are importing Header, Footer and other Navigation components from shared library into other projects. In these components we are using Link, NavLink components for navigation. Below is the structure of our MonoRepo ( we are using npm workspaces for this monorepo ).

MonoRepo

- shared
- project1
- project2

Now I am trying to upgrade react-router-dom to v6 from v5 but I am having issues on rendering the components with Link or react-router-dom related components in our main projects ( project1/ project2 ).

My Footer component in shared library is like below:

```
const Footer = () => <Link to="/">Some image</Link>;
```

Below is my AppLayout in project1 and importing the above Footer component from shared:

```
import Footer from 'shared';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import User from './User';

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
    <Route path="/user" element={<User />}>
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```

I got the below error when I try to render this in the webpage.

[image]

So I wrapped Footer component with BrowserRouter like below in shared repo.

```
const Footer = () => <BrowserRouter><Link to="/">Some image</Link></BrowserRouter>;
```

Now, I didn't get any error and able to render the footer on the browser but somehow routing is not working. I am suspecting this is because of the 2nd BrowserRouter that I have in my Footer component.

Please check and help me out with this.

Comment: If you want to render the `Footer` always, put it our of `BrowserRouter`. And clear `BrowserRouter` that you put to wrapped the Footer component.

Comment: I tried that and no luck!. Looks like it is checking for the Router context while importing not while rendering. Because I am rendering it inside BrowserRouter itself.

Comment: I found one hack, somehow Footer from shared library is not able to access the context created by Router in parent project. So I ended up passing Link component as a prop to the Footer and use that instead of using Link from react-router-dom.